# Proof of Problem 26 in Chapter 7 of Royden's Real Analysis 3ed.

Tags: real-analysis

There is a hint for Problem $26$ in Chapter $7$ of Royden's Real Analysis $3$ed., which states as below.

> Let $O$ be an open subset of a complete metric space $(X, \rho)$. Hint: Let $\varphi(x) = [\rho(x, \tilde{O})]^{-1}$ for each $x \in O$, where $\tilde{O}$ is the complement of $O$ and $\rho(x, \tilde{O}) = \inf_{y \in \tilde{O}} \rho(x, y)$ is the distance of $x$ to $\tilde{O}$. Then $\{\langle x, y \rangle : x \in O, y = \varphi(x)\}$ is a closed, and therefore complete, subset of $X \times \mathbb{R}$.

I cannot figure out why the set $\{\langle x, y \rangle : x \in O, y = \varphi(x)\}$ is closed. Please provide your kind help, many thanks!

Comment: Do you have the topologists definition of continuous function? : "the continuous preimage of an open set is open".

Comment: @Gae.S. I've updated the question according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\lim_{n\to\infty}\langle x_n,\varphi(x_n)\rangle= \langle x,y\rangle$ with $x\in\widetilde O$ then, by continuity of $\rho(\bullet,\widetilde O)$, we'd have $\rho(x_n,\widetilde O)\to\rho(x,\widetilde O)=0$ and, therefore, $\varphi(x_n)\to\infty$. Therefore no such sequence exists, which means $$\operatorname{cl}_{X\times\Bbb R}\{\langle x,y\rangle\,:\, x\in O\land y=\varphi(x)\}\subseteq O\times \Bbb R.$$ Therefore, $$\operatorname{cl}_{X\times\Bbb R}\{\langle x,y\rangle\,:\, x\in O\land y=\varphi(x)\}=\operatorname{cl}_{O\times\Bbb R}\{\langle x,y\rangle\,:\, x\in O\land y=\varphi(x)\}$$

But $\varphi:O\to\Bbb R$ is continuous and $\Bbb R$ is Hausdorff, therefore its graph is already closed in the product $O\times \Bbb R$.

Comment: Thank you! I agree with the first part of your explanation, which is a sequence in the set $\{\langle x, y \rangle : x \in O, y = \varphi(x)\}$ cannot converge to a point in $\tilde{O}$. However, for your statement that the graph of $\varphi$ is closed in $O \times \mathbb{R}$, I checked Problem 8 on P171 of James Munkres' "Topology", it also requires $\mathbb{R}$ to be compact. However, this is not true.

Comment: @TJH The first part of my argument is, strictly speaking, that a sequence in $\{\langle x,y\rangle\,:\, x\in O, y=\varphi(x)\}$ cannot converge to a point in $\widetilde O\times \Bbb R$. It is always true that if $Y$ is Hausdorff and $f:X\to Y$ is continuous, then the graph of $f$ is closed in $X\times Y$. What's special in the case $Y$ compact Hausdorff is that if $g:X\to Y$ is discontinuous, then the graph of $g$ is not closed in $X\times Y$.

Comment: Then I understand! I am sincerely thankful for your explanation!